# Add two list index wise in python but list 1 has a value list 2 has no value means it needs to display the list1

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The question was merge two list index wise
eg:

```
a = [ab,bc,cd]
b = []
```

expected output:

```
ans = [ab,bc,cd]
```

I have tried this

```
a = input("enter the list 1:")
list1 = a.split(",")
b = input("enter the list 2:")
list2 = b.split(",")

if list2 == EMPTY_LIST:
    print(list1)
else:
    res = [i+j for i, j in zip(list1,list2)] 
    print("Ans: ",res)
```

but the output is

```
enter the list 1:abi,ajith
enter the list 2:
Ans:  ['abi']
```

expected output i need

```
enter the list 1:abi,ajith
enter the list 2:
Ans:  ['abi','ajith']
```

Comment: To check if a list is empty: ``if not list2:``

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here.  First of all, input always returns a string.  If you didn't type anything before hitting the return, it will be an empty string.  Therefore, in your program,

```
b = ''  # an empty string
```

The split function always returns a list of strings.  If called on the empty string, it returns a list containing one element, the empty string.  Therefore, in your program,

```
list2 = ['']
```

This is not an empty list.  It contains 1 element.  If you use it a boolean expression, its value is True because it contains a nonzero number of elements.  Therefore:

```
bool(list2) = True
```

and so your if expression `if not list2` fails.  The code takes the else branch, as you can see because your output begins with the text "Ans:".

Now the zip function terminates as soon as ONE of its sequences ends.  list1 contains 2 elements but list2 contains only one, so only 1 iteration occurs.  Only one element gets printed.  That explains exactly what you see.

Programming requires you to think about and understand every detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following please:

```
a = input("enter the list 1:")
list1 = a.split(",")
b = input("enter the list 2:")
list2 = b.split(",")

if not list2:
    print(list1)
else:
    res = [_ for _ in (list1+list2) if len(_)]
    print("Ans: ",res)
```

Comment: No bro it also not display the second index                                                                   
 enter the list 1:abi,ajith
enter the list 2:
Ans:  ['abi']

Comment: enter the list 1:abi,ajith
enter the list 2:
Ans:  ['abi', 'ajith']

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: ya bro it works fine

Comment: @AbilashK.G i have edited my answer it works for empty lists now

Comment: @AshishSamarth Your code fails for no input

Comment: Well their are a quite a few ways it can fail, providing answers here are with the focus on the question itself, rather than how many ways it can fail

Answer (score 0):

You were checking an empty list the wrong way. Since the user did not enter anything, you cannot check if the list is empty or not. Or I should say that list will not be empty since it will be equal to `['']`.  You need to check if the input is empty.

```
a = input("enter the list 1:")
list1 = a.split(",")
print(list1)
b = input("enter the list 2:")
list2 = b.split(",")

if not b: # This is the way of checking if an input is empty or not
    print(list1)
else:
    res = [i+j for i, j in zip(list1,list2)] 
    print("Ans: ",res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also handle the case where `list2` is not empty but does not have the same number of elements as `list1`

If you pad the list with empty strings, you can then zip them without issue

```
n=max(len(list1),len(list2))
for i in range(n):
   if i >= len(list1): a.append("")
   if i >= len(list2): b.append("")

res = [i+j for i, j in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Or perhaps a simpler way:

```
import itertools as it
list1 = ["ab","bc","cd"]
list2 = []

[i+j for i, j in it.zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue="")]
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. OP wanted input from user and then use it for merging

Comment: The input is two lists... the way the OP handles the input works with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input`, it returns a string, even if you don't  pass any value in it. So it will return `''` so `list2` will not be empty.

You can fix it by checking if `''` is not the `list` and also list lenght is 1:

```
if len(list2) ==1 and '' in list2 :
    print(list1)
else:
    res = [i+j for i, j in zip(list1,list2)] 
    print("Ans: ",res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if list2 == []:
    print(list1)
```

Comment: no bro it display same output enter the list 1:abi,ajith
enter the list 2:
Ans:  ['abi'] I need ajith also in the output